# How do I create an array of abstract class objects in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, polymorphism, matlab-class

As an example, suppose I have created an abstract class called `Shape` and two subclasses called `Circle` and `Rectangle` that both implement an (abstract) method called `Draw`. I would like to be able to create a number of `Circle` and `Rectangle` objects, store them in an array and call `Draw` on each array object by iterating through the array.

I have tried something like the following:

Shape.m:

```
classdef (Abstract) Shape < handle

    methods (Abstract)
        Draw(obj);
    end

end
```

Circle.m:

```
classdef Circle < Shape

    methods
        function obj = Draw(obj)
            disp('This is a circle');
        end
    end

end
```

Rectangle.m:

```
classdef Rectangle < Shape

    methods
        function obj = Draw(obj)
            disp('This is a rectangle');
        end
    end

end
```

test.m:

```
shapes = Shape.empty();

myrect = Rectangle();
mycirc = Circle();

shapes(end + 1) = myrect;
shapes(end + 1) = mycirc;

for i = 1:size(shapes,1)
    shapes(i).Draw();
end
```

When I try to run test.m, I get the following error message:

```
Error using Shape.empty
Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.
Class 'Shape' defines abstract methods
and/or properties.

Error in test (line 1)
shapes = Shape.empty();
```

Answer (score 16):

As is clear from the error, [you cannot instantiate an abstract class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/abstract-classes-and-interfaces.html) (see sebastian's answer for details). However, there is a special superclass called [`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneousclass.html) from which you can derive to allow creation of an array of different classes.

First, derive from `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` in Shape.m:

```
classdef (Abstract) Shape < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
```

Then in your test script, initialize `shapes` from either `Circle` or `Rectangle`:

```
shapes = Circle.empty();
```

When you run the loop, the array will change class:

```
>> shapes

shapes = 

  1x2 heterogeneous Shape (Rectangle, Circle) array with no properties.

>> shapes(1)

ans = 

  Rectangle with no properties.

>> shapes(2)

ans = 

  Circle with no properties.
```

That should be all you need, but for additional control over a heterogeneous array, you can override [the getDefaultScalarElement method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous.getdefaultscalarelement.html) of `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` to specify the default object. This should be overridden for abstract base classes:

> **Override this method if the Root Class is abstract** or is not an appropriate default object for the classes in the heterogeneous hierarchy. getDefaultScalarElement must return an instance of another member of the heterogeneous hierarchy.

Say you want the default object to be `Circle` for an array of objects deriving from `Shape`:

```
methods (Static, Sealed, Access = protected)
    function default_object = getDefaultScalarElement
        default_object = Circle;
    end
end
```

Now missing elements in an array of objects derived from `Shape` will be filled with `Circle` objects:

```
>> clear r
>> r(2) = Rectangle
r = 
  1x2 heterogeneous Shape (Circle, Rectangle) array with no properties.
>> r(1)
ans = 
  Circle with no properties.
>> r(2)
ans = 
  Rectangle with no properties.
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

```
abstract class — A class that cannot be instantiated, but that defines class components used by subclasses.
```

See: [Mathworks-Docs](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/abstract-classes-and-interfaces.html#btgxhq8)

Which is, afaik, the definition of abstract classes in other programming languages as well (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

So to construct an array that holds various kinds of `Shape` elements, I'd guess you'll either have to make `Shape` non-abstract or implement another non-abstract class, that all your real implementations inherit from.

**EDIT:** For completeness:

I tried what you're trying achieve and at first sight, object-arrays with mixed elements that have a common superclass don't exist:

```
>> objects(1) = Foo();
>> objects(2) = FooBar();
The following error occurred converting from FooBar to Foo:
Error using Foo
Too many input arguments.

>> FooBar

ans = 

  FooBar handle with no properties.
  Methods, Events, Superclasses


Superclasses for class FooBar:

    Foo
    handle
```

**EDIT 2:** 
See chappjc's solution for this issue ;)