# Matlab: Creating arrays of objects that inherit from a parent class

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, inheritance

In Matlab I have three classes. The parent class is an abstract class named `Zone`. It has two child classes that inherit from it. They are `IZone` and `SZone`.

I have a fourth class called `System` that is supposed to have an array of `Zone` objects. However, when I create the array and pass in an `SZone` object, the array becomes an array of type `SZone` and Matlab won't let me add any `IZone` objects to it.

If I add an `IZone` and `SZone` at the same time, it creates an array of type `Zone`. But I never actually do this. I only add one zone at a time. Is there some way to cast the array to a type of `Zone`? Like in Java?

Right now I'm considering changing the array to a cell array. But I'd prefer to keep this as an array of objects of type `Zone`.

Note: `Zone` doesn't have to be Abstract.

**EDIT**

I found a similar question here about specifically abstract classes. So this question might be a duplicate.

[How do I create an array of abstract class objects in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900418/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-abstract-class-objects-in-matlab?rq=1)

Comment: I think my only option here is to create another object called ZoneArray that overloads the subsref function. I'd really really really rather not have to do that though. It seems like I'd have to use a cell array inside that object, and then I might as well just use a cell array.

Comment: I have flagged my own question as a duplicate. The matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous solution worked!